# Instance labelling issue in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

Prometheus seems to be labelling and setting other metadata for the target instances in an incorrect way, possibly due to a mis-configuration.

Here's the config, to scrape multiple targets and label each one:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 5s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']
        labels:
          host: 'Server0'
          service: 'Prometheus'

  - job_name: 'node_exporter'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9100']
        labels:
          host: 'Server0'

  - job_name: 'wmi_exporter'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9100']
        labels:
          host: 'Server1'
      - targets: ['xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9100']
        labels:
          host: 'Server2'
```

All targets appear UP in the Prometheus admin UI. But when I run a query for `prometheus_sd_discovered_targets`, it returns targets with the same `job` name, `instance` address, `host` & `service` labels:

```
prometheus_sd_discovered_targets{config="node_exporter",host="Local",instance="localhost:9090",job="prometheus",name="scrape",service="Prometheus"}     1

prometheus_sd_discovered_targets{config="prometheus",host="Local",instance="localhost:9090",job="prometheus",name="scrape",service="Prometheus"}     1

prometheus_sd_discovered_targets{config="wmi_exporter",host="Local",instance="localhost:9090",job="prometheus",name="scrape",service="Prometheus"}     2
```

Why are metadata values the same for all targets, even though they're configured & labelled differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prometheus_sd_discovered_targets` is a metric exported by Prometheus (not node exporter, not wmi exporter) so all those timeseries come from your only Prometheus instance, i.e. `host="Local",instance="localhost:9090",job="prometheus",service="Prometheus"`.

The `name="scrape",config="wmi_exporter"` labels come from the metric itself, because if you check `http://localhost:9090/metrics`, you'll find (among other things) something like this:

```
prometheus_sd_discovered_targets{name="scrape",config="node_exporter"} 1
prometheus_sd_discovered_targets{name="scrape",config="prometheus"} 1
prometheus_sd_discovered_targets{name="scrape",config="wmi_exporter"} 2
```